# Is it true, that Android vertical scroll is for information only? But how to scroll grid, that is full with actionable content?

Tags: android, scrolling, scrollbars

Vertical Scroll on Android is rare. https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-scrollview-horizontal-vertical-with-examples has animation of one such scroll and Microsoft Outlook web application (old style) is another example. Both cases show that scrollbar is so narrow that it is impossible to use it for actual scrolling with this, it seems to me that these scrollbars are for indication only? So, is it true, that Android vertical scroll can be for the information only?

But how to handle the situation when the content is grid that is full with actionaly content? I can not just touch any spot in this content, becuase then field become editable, the popup menus or selection lists opens, etc. I have thought about adding very wide scrollbar to implement scorlling, but apparently this could be very strange. I can preserve the information narrow scroll, but I feel that I should be some non-hot are in my content that can be used for the touching and scrolling only.

Note, that my uses cases involves predetermined length list, no infinite scrolling.

Is all this really true about Android scroll UIX?

Answer (score 1):

> I can not just touch any spot in this content, becuase then field become editable, the popup menus or selection lists opens, etc

A touch on its own isn't an input - a quick tap, a long press and a swipe are all distinct actions which you can detect without too much issue. I'd recommend looking at something like Google Sheets to see how they've done these interactions - touching a scroll bar is never necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all content is interactive.
Now it is very rare to find places in the application where only informational content (lists, documents...)

As Leo said, swiping across the screen is not a tap. You can see an example in the old version of the material.
https://m1.material.io/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior